# moving from CodeIgniter to ASP.NET - don't understand default controller actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am familiar with CodeIgniter so I'm not a newbie, but I sure feel like one as I move to MVC using C#/.NET. I would expect calling the below controller would properly bind the slash-delimited arguments of URL to the controller input params. Eg: I would expect `http://localhost/Download/51` to give fileID=51. However, when I run this, fileID is null when controller is called. Either HttpGet needs querystring with ? and & or  need to modify routes somehow to bind properly. Help, please?

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Download(String fileID)                
    {
    ....// http://localhost/Download/51 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use `id` which is the default route parameter name configured in your `Global.asax`:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Download(string id)
{
    ....// http://localhost/Download/51 
}
```

or change your routing configuration so that `fileID` is used:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{fileid}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", fileid = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Also checkout the [following](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/controllers-and-routing) for more details on routing.

Comment: Much thanks! Didn't realize param names need to match between route and controller.